# Вывод подсказок при заполнении формы

Tags: html

Заметил такую штуку, на некоторых сайтах, при клике на строку ввода в форме, подсказка с ранее веденными даными появляется и фиксируется на экрана при скроле, а на остальных сайтах при скроле подсказка пропадает. От чего это зависит и как это можно реализовать (без использования своих подсказок).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: autocomplete="on" на сайте есть уже развёрнутые ответы на эту тему

Comment: При добавлении autocomplete="on", подсказка все равно исчезает, там, связано как то со стилями

Comment: Если думаете, там стили какие-то особые, попробуйте зайти на те сайты, где работает, как вам хочется, и посмотреть в Dev Tools на элемент и стили. Но если со скроллом связано, думаю, это js, css не управляет прокруткой (по крайней мере так было, когда я последний раз интересовалась этим вопросом)